# filling a vector with a numberline from negative to positive in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a range of values with a +/- interval given a mid point. The mid point and intervals are variables and can change.

For example, if my mid point is 0 and my interval is 5, I want my vector to be comprised of

```
[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

If my mid point is 140 and interval is 5, the vector would be

```
[135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145]
```

I initially thought this would be easy to do in a single for loop. But I am totally stumped on how to do this in an elegant fashion in R

The only way I can think off is to calculate the negative and positive values separately and then join the elements to form a vector.

Comment: 2nd option: `140 + -5:5`

Comment: This is very simple and neat, however the answer provided by Harrison enables me to use the midpoint, interval and steps as a function. Thank you for you answer though, it will definitely come in handy for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this which uses the `seq()` function:

```
mid_int <- function(mid_point, interval) {
  seq(mid_point - interval, mid_point + interval, by = 1)
}

mid_int(0, 5)
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5

mid_int(140, 5)
 [1] 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Elegant without the use of for loops, yet with enough flexibility to use as a function. Thank You!